# Remove parameters within nginx rewrite

Tags: get, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm rewriting URLs in nginx after a relaunch. In the old site I had query parameters in the URL to filter stuff e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.php?type=4
```

The new page doesn't have these kind of parameters. I want to remove them and rewrite the URLs to the main page, so that I get:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage/
```

My rewrite rule in nginx is:

```
location ^~ /mypage.php {
    rewrite ^/mypage.php$ http://www.example.com/mypage permanent;
}
```

But with this rule the parameter is still appended. I thought the `$` would stop nginx from processing further values... any ideas? All other questions deal with how to add parameters - I just want to remove mine :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Had a similar problem, after a lot of searching the answer presented itself in the [rewrite docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite).

> If you specify a ? at the end of a rewrite then Nginx will drop the original $args (arguments)

So for your example, this would do the trick:

```
location ^~ /mypage.php {
    rewrite ^/mypage.php$ http://www.example.com/mypage? permanent;
}
```

Comment: You have better reading skills than I have ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: What about I want to drop a specific parameter.

Comment: wait, wouldn't this rule cause a redirect loop?

Comment: This works even if your destination has a query string: 
rewrite ^/abc$ http://example.com/a?b=c? permanent;

Answer (score 15):

To drop a parameter from a URL, in this case `coupon=xxx`:

```
if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)coupon=(.*)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

Note that this will drop all parameters if the 
statement matches.  `$uri` is the original request without parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the `$args` variable to empty inside the location.

```
set $args '';
```

Comment: That will break this type of operation where you want to use a query parameter value to add a new header:  proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_token";

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove a specified parameter from url,

```
#  in location directive: 
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)unwanted=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1; 
    set $args1 $2; 
    set $unwanted $3; 
    set $args2 $4; 
    set $args ""; 

    rewrite ^ "${original_path}?${args1}${args2}" permanent;
}
```

then visit your_site.com/a=1&unwanted=2&c=3

step1. server gives an 302 response, indicating the url is match.

step2. client re-send a request with the new url ( with the parameter removed)

Comment: Aren’t IF conditions considered evil in Nginx world?

Comment: Note. Use `break;` instead of `permanent;` to keep the same url in the browser.

Comment: @KhomNazid, they are evil only if you use them for things _other then rewrite_. See: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/#what-to-do-instead