# nginx rewrite: URL query removal

Tags: regex, redirect, amazon-web-services, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi I have implemented a Rails app with nginx and deployed on Amazon Web Services.

I have written different rules for 301 redirection.

On of them is the following in `nginx.conf`:

```
rewrite (?i)^/abc/HomePage.aspx(.*) /#!/Home$1 permanent;
```

However I am able to redirect to home page but am having trailing characters in the URL, which can be dynamic.

For example, if the URL (old site) is `http://x3.com/abc/HomePage.aspx?_=72HNtUhJkGN5yXngjof0jLZ1yv7ykDfnNwsiYcgx9xqpVoLH0UvC5nneQnFfwTQnnC5w4nYtXuBc7DIA16BxkA==`

it is landing on `http://www.x3.com/#!/Home?_=72HNtUhJkGN5yXngjof0jLZ1yv7ykDfnNwsiYcgx9xqpVoLH0UvC5nneQnFfwTQnnC5w4nYtXuBc7DIA16BxkA`

I just want to remove the trailing part which is `_=72HNtUhJkGN5yXngjof0jLZ1yv7ykDfnNwsiYcgx9xqpVoLH0UvC5nneQnFfwTQnnC5w4nYtXuBc7DIA16BxkA`

and land on `http://www.x3.com/#!/Home`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a base64 encoded string. The padding (== characters) gets truncated because = in the URL is used to assign parameters. You should urlencode the string so that equal signs become '%3D'.

Comment: @alkar but what will that achieve in my question..I actually want to redirect.I am not concerned what comes after .aspx and want to discard this.Do you have any solution

Comment: If you do that, the redirect should work I believe. Can you try visiting the following URL and see if the redirect works? http://www.x3.com/#!/Home?_=72HNtUhJkGN5yXngjof0jLZ1yv7ykDfnNwsiYcgx9xqpVoLH0UvC5nneQnFfwTQnnC5w4nYtXuBc7DIA16BxkA%3D%3D

Comment: @alkar I am getting /Home?_=72HNtUhJkGN5yXngjof0jLZ1yv7ykDfnNwsiYcgx9xqpVoLH0UvC5nneQnFfwTQnnC5w4nYtXuBc7DIA16BxkA%3D%3D

Comment: Oops sorry, misread one bit of the question. From your redirect statement in nginx try to remove `$1`. It should fix this.

Comment: @alkar Ok will try.thanks..Should i keep permanent or remove that too

Comment: @alkar No it didn't work

Comment: Permanent depends on the type of redirection you want. Make sure you have disabled your browser's cache before testing. Due to the permanent keyword if you're using the cache it will not work.

Comment: @alkar Still dint work

Comment: Try to change it back to `/#!/Home$1?` (notice the extra question mark at the end).

Comment: @alkar Yess It worked ..Thanks a lot ..Can you please give it as answer as i can give you a upvote and it can help others like me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove parameters within nginx rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641603/remove-parameters-within-nginx-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a trailing `?` to the rewrite url as per the [docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite):

```
rewrite (?i)^/abc/HomePage.aspx(.*) /#!/Home$1? permanent;
```

Make sure to clear the browser cache before testing.

Also, regarding `permanent` redirection refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393298/95656).