# Remove query parameter in nginx if present

Tags: http, nginx, lua

In an nginx config, I am trying to add a parameter which add a http request parameters. A `x_user_id` is present as an http header, this should be added as a query parameter

`http://somehost:8080/someurl?foo=bar` ( Header `x_user_id` `1234` )
should be redirected to 
`http://otherhost?foo=bar&userId=1234`

Also, if the `user_id` parameter is present, it should be removed:

`http://somehost:8080/someurl?foo=bar&userId=6666` ( Header `x_user_id`  `1234`)
should be redirected to 
`http://otherhost?foo=bar&userId=1234`

Now I have seen the question [Nginx Redirect - Remove a specific query parameter from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384776/nginx-redirect-remove-a-specific-query-parameter-from-url) , but it seems quite cryptic to do this in nginx. Also this document says that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

I have tried somethng like

```
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)?userId=([^&]*)[&]?(.*)") {
   set $original_path $1;
   set $args1 $2;
   set $unwanted $3;
   set $args2 $4;
   set $args "";

   proxy_pass https://httpbin.org/get?${args1}${args2} ;
}
```

but, first it is not working.
It would probably be possible to get it to work, but it will probably be unmaintainable and quite cryptic.

I have also seen there is a module lua, and by using that, it seems to be easier and a more high-level programming model can be used like that:

```
local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
local headers = ngx.req.get_headers()

args.userId = nil -- remove user_id parameter
args.userId = headers.x_user_id

ngx.req.set_uri_args(args)
```

This seems well-readable for someone who is not familiar with nginx config.
Unfortunately, lua is not included in vanilla nginx and therefore I can't use it.

**How to do this is a manner which does not make the config files too cryptic?**

**Is nginx even the right place to do that?**

Comment: Usually no one seriously use nginx installed as system package, because we for production we need only required nginx modules. What is the problem to build nginx with Lua module? Or best to use OpenResty as ready to use bundle and build it with only required modules?

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler: Well if I understand that correctly, you mean building nginx from sources. Since nginx is installed using ansible, this means I would have to install a GCC, libraries necessary and so on in ansible, which is time-consuming (and as usual, there is no time) just install it using a package manager

Comment: install Docker and then run nginx with bundled Lua module from suitable openresty/openresty image from GitHub. It has Lua module bundled. Here is the example https://github.com/quantmind/ansible-openresty