# Nginx rewrite only for certain parameters of query for Facebook fbclid

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

How to write a **rewrite** for the **Nginx** that will take into account **only certain** parameters of query:

For example, I have a query:

```
site.com/guru/?g=guru1&skill=basic&unwanted=garbage
```

I want to receive:

```
site.com/guru/?g=guru1&skill=basic
```

I think about:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772678/1895392

```
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)unwanted=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1;
    set $args1 $2;
    set $unwanted $3;
    set $args2 $4;
    set $args "";
    rewrite ^ "${original_path}?${args1}${args2}" permanent;
}
```

Thank.

Comment: Hi, is the linked SO answer not working for you ? If you can be specific about your requirement I can help you. Do you need to remove a specific parameter `unwanted` that can occur anywhere in the uri ? Or is your uri structure predictable and your need to remove everything that occurs after parameter `unwanted` including the parameter ? For ex. a simple rewrite for your use case above can be achieved using `rewrite ^(site.*)(?=&unwanted) $1`

Comment: The address structure is predictable.
An undesirable parameter is the most recent, but it may not be.
We are talking about the innovation of Facebook. Now the **fbclid=123456** parameter is added to each link. This parameter I want to exclude.

Thank.