# Nginx Strip URL Parameters

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to strip url params before send it to proxy_pass

For visitor request url:
=> https://example.com/?wanted1=aaa&unwanted1=bbb&unwanted2=ccc&wanted2=ddd

Then it strip all the unwanted params to:
=> https://example.com/?wanted1=aaa&wanted2=ddd

My current way is like this:

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)&(?:unwanted1|unwanted2)=[^&]*(&.*)?$ ) {
    set $args $1$2;
}
```

But It only remove 1 param and never do recursion. How to solve this? I want to modify the $args.

Comment: Have you tried using two `if...set` blocks, one for each unwanted parameter?

Comment: Does this question answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384776/nginx-redirect-remove-a-specific-query-parameter-from-url

Comment: @RichardSmith No. It will not work if I have the same string multiple times https://example.com/?unwanted2=aaa&unwanted2=aaa it will just remove the first unwanted2

Comment: @patrick Its using rewrite which will not modify the $args

Answer (score 1):

If you want recursion, you can use a `rewrite...last` from within a `location` block. Nginx will only tolerate a small number of recursions (possibly ten iterations) before generating an internal server error.

For example:

```
location / {
    if ($args ~ ^(?<prefix>.*)&(?:unwanted1|unwanted2)=[^&]*(?<suffix>&.*)?$ ) {
        rewrite ^ $uri?$prefix$suffix? last;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that you need to use named captures as the numbered captures are reset when the `rewrite` statement is evaluated.

Note that `rewrite` requires a trailing `?` to prevent the existing arguments being appended to the rewritten URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Its almost working. Just a little problem:

hxxps://example.com/tester.php?unwanted1=111&unwanted2=222&unwanted2=222 will be rewrited to hxxps://example.com/tester.php?unwanted1=111

So our 'unwanted param' will not get stripped if its on the first place.

Comment: Your regular expression currently requires the unwanted parameter to be proceeded by an `&`. Try: `^(?:(?<prefix>.*)&)?(?:unwanted1|unwanted2)=[^&]*(?<suffix>&.*)?$`