# Nginx: Remove Single Query String parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server that returns a 301 HTTP redirect url which contains an API key. The redirect hits Nginx and in there I need to add an `Authorization` HTTP Header that contains the value of the API key. I want to then remove the API key from the query parameters that get sent through

I need to translate `/google/?search=abcde&apikey=1234&version=1` to `/google/?search=abcde&version=1`

**Code**

```
location /google/ {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    Authorization       "Bearer $arg_apikey";
    proxy_pass          https://google.com/;
}
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:
[Remove parameters within nginx rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641603/remove-parameters-within-nginx-rewrite)

```
location /google/ {
    if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)apikey=(.*)$") {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
    }
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    Authorization       "Bearer $arg_apikey";
    proxy_pass          https://google.com/;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do. Your `if` block removes the entire query string with a 301 redirect. Are you trying to surgically remove the `apikey=1234` part only, and them send the remaining URI upstream with the `proxy_pass`?

Comment: @RichardSmith exactly

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to apply a regular expression to the `$request_uri` variable (which contains the original request including query string) and capture everything before and after the parameter to be removed.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $newuri {
    default                                   $request_uri;
    ~^(?<prefix>.*)apikey=[^&]+(?<suffix>.*)$ $prefix$suffix;
}
server {
    ...
    location /google/ {
        resolver ...;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Authorization       "Bearer $arg_apikey";
        proxy_pass          https://google.com$newuri;
    }
    ...
}
```

You could probably achieve a similar result with an `if` block. In this example, the `proxy_pass` statement is constructed using a `map` variable. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

You will probably need to define a `resolver` because of the variable in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for details.

Comment: Great, the moment I've got this sorted and working I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if ($args ~ (.*)&(apikey=[^&]*)(?=&|$)(.*)|^(apikey=[^&]*)(&|$)(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$6;
    rewrite ^ $uri permanent;
}
```

in place of your:

```
if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)apikey=(.*)$") {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```